# Remove WatchKit App From Deployed App - iOS WatchOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, watchos

If I deploy an iOS app on the apple App Store with a WatchOS extension/project can I later remove the Apple Watch extension/project from the same app store listing or will I have to support the watch app indefinitely moving forward?

I know once you support iPad there is no way to remove iPad support, I am wondering if this is also the case of Apple Watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the WatchKit Extension from your iOS app even after you deployed the watchOS app to the AppStore. You simply need to remove the Apple Watch targets from your Xcode project and then upload an update to the AppStore.